# Optimal concurrency/partitioning for dask apply?

Tags: dask

I'm using `apply` over a dataframe column 
(hope I should not be using `apply_map` instead, the docs aren't clear about it). I'd like to squeeze the most out of an idle multi-core big memory machine.

Am I using an optimal combination of number of workers, threads, and partitions?

```
client = Client(n_workers=cpu_count()-2, threads_per_worker=1, memory_limit='1GB')

ddf = daskDataFrame.from_pandas(df, npartitions=cpu_count()-2)

ddf['candidate'] = ddf['text'].apply(get_sameness_candidate, meta=('candidate', 'str'))
```

Should I look at the function I'm applying to be able to answer this for myself, or is the tuning of this scenario agnostic of that and thusly we have a rule of thumb?

Thanks!

Comment: would also be nice learning whether any of the dashboard tabs is actually showing in real time how much of the dataframe (or column) has been so far processed or the row processing rate / ETA. Thanks for making Dask!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid, the only way to know the optimal setup for a given parallel computation is benchmarking. Many variables affect the performance: the volume of the data and the size of the individual chunks, the complexity of the computation, how much CPU it needs and how much memory is needed for intermediates within the function, whether the function releases the GIL, how much communication is required between workers...

The fact that you are using `from_pandas` suggests that your computation would need to be CPU intensive to see a good benefit from Dask, since obviously it must fit into the client machine's memory as a single pandas dataframe.

Some suggestions are [here](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/efficiency.html), and the distributed dashboard will show you what's going on, including the current state of the submitted graph and profiling of code running on the workers. This answers the question in the comment; you do *not* get row-level information, since Dask does not know a priori how many rows are within each partition of the dataframe.

Comment: Well thanks again. Indeed my computation is compute intensive. It's great having that efficiency small section in the docs there. What I'm not sure of is how the number of partitions connects, for example, how much does a small/large number of partitions, change how the workers split their work, or what other implications would the number of partitions have. I hope it's easy to drop a brief comment or reference about how to think about partition sizes here!

Comment: You certainly want enough partitions to keep all the cores busy, and big enough partitions so that the overhear for running each task is small compared to the work done, but small enough so that a set of partitions plus any required intermediates does not fill up memory.